# WPF user control that slides out either left or right with an array of buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

Firstly, **I am new to WPF** and have inherited a legacy application that needs improving.
I need to replace an existing single button with a new kind of user control.

Secondly, I have searched the web for WPF examples of the user control functionality I am interested in and cannot find it.
I don't think it exists, but I don't know what it is called and so I may not be searching with the correct name.
The best name I can come up with is *button-slider-flyout* control (hehe).

I need a user control with the same functionality as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU7d7.png) (orginal image url https://i.stack.imgur.com/82wru.jpg).

You will notice the picture is a character gear screen where a user has extended a slide panel for tabards. The functionality of the button slider is what I am looking for.

I suppose what I am after is something like a ComboBox with custom behaviour.

1. Instead of a drop-down list, I need a slide-left or slide-right list (perhaps a slide-direction property).
2. The list items should allow me to assign a text value but display images instead of description text.
3. After selecting an item, the slider should collapse and the main image should become the same as the selected items image.
4. The SelectedValue property should be set to the value of the selected items value.
5. Code should fire for the chosen item, either via the selectedindex_changed event or the items themselves could have click behaviour.

Does this user control already exist in WPF? If so what is it called?

If the control does not exist can someone please give an example of how to build it?

As an example, I can imagine the following XAML for the completed control...

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" ...>
    <Button x:Name="moveButton" Click="moveButton_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="moveIcon.png" .../>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
</Border>
<Border Grid.Row="1" ...>
    <ButtonSliderFlyout x:Name="addButtonSlider" SlideDirection="Left">

        <!-- DEFAULT ICON AND HAS NO CLICK BEHAVIOUR -->
        <ButtonSliderFlyoutItem x:Name="addItem" Value="Add">
            <ButtonSliderFlyoutItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="addIcon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </ButtonSliderFlyoutItem.Background>
        </ButtonSliderFlyoutItem>

        <!-- ITEM1 WITH CLICK BEHAVIOUR -->
        <ButtonSliderFlyoutItem x:Name="addItem1" Value="AddItem1" Click="addItem1_Click">
            <ButtonSliderFlyoutItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="addItem1Icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </ButtonSliderFlyoutItem.Background>
        </ButtonSliderFlyoutItem>

        <!-- ITEM2 WITH CLICK BEHAVIOUR -->
        <ButtonSliderFlyoutItem x:Name="addItem2" Value="AddItem2" Click="addItem2_Click">
            <ButtonSliderFlyoutItem.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="addItem2Icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </ButtonSliderFlyoutItem.Background>
        </ButtonSliderFlyoutItem>
    </ButtonSliderFlyout>
</Border>
```

Comment: The most relevant keyword for this in WPF is "ItemTemplate", use it with "Combobox"/"WPF" you may find some useful stuff.

Comment: [this page](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/combobox/) provides some simple examples, you can get an idea of what `ItemTemplate` is and how you would define the layout in the template.

Comment: Does the [Expander](https://wpftutorial.net/Expander.html) control give you some of your required functionality?

Comment: The itemtemplate article is useful and I can see how I would format the combobox items to display just my images, thank you! I still need to change the behaviour of the control to pop left or right instead of down.

Comment: @PaulF, the expander control looks like it may solve my second problem. I can see it supports a direction property including left/right. I tested this and noticed the content 'pushes' the expander header to the right. I need a float effect like the content of the dropdown list. I did notice that I can contain an expander in a canvas to achieve this effect but I am starting to get out of my depth. Thank you for the tip though

Comment: This can absolutely be done but requires some reasonably involved editing of templates. If the examples I've done in the past weren't restricted by NDA's I'd happily share them or maybe if I can find time next week to make a decent example but this remains still a pretty broad question. Start with a ComboBox, ditch the ItemsPresenter and make another panel like StackPanel Horizontal as IsItemsHost=True and then it just gets more and more deep from there (depending how cool you want it) with animations and DOM rendering etc. Not a simple quick question to answer unfortunately. Sorry :(